# Change between US and Canadian spellings in an email in SFMC emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder, email-studio

I am sure other SFMC users would have had bumped into a similar use case where they want to spell words differently for US vs Canadian or US vs an international audience. I haven't been able to find an out-of-the-box solution or a hub exchange app to make this happen. Has anyone been able to figure out an innovative way to do this? Or is there an out-of-the-box functionality in Content Builder or via AmpScript that does this? Look forward to get some interesting feedback on this post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an interesting use case, I haven't heard of internationalization in Content Builder. You can select a Target language - UTF-8 or other encoding formats (Chinese, Japanese etc), but not where it will translate your email based on the audience.  You'll have to manually build separate content blocks for US vs Canada and manually enter the words spelled differently. If you find a solution, do share.

Comment: Rajdeep, it appears ampscript is the only way to do it. It felt little less scalable but I guess that's the way to do it, for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a few projects where this is required and the easiest way to get this done is have dynamic content which is region based. We use AMPscript IF statements to get this done. There is no 'Out-of-the-box' functionality for this unfortunately. See below example:

```
SET @Region = 'Canada'

IF @Region == 'Canada' THEN
  SET @text1 = 'Hello I'm from Canada'
ELSEIF @Region == 'America' THEN
  SET @text1 = 'Hello I'm from America'
ENDIF
```

OR in the HTML:

```
%%=IIF(@Region == 'Canada','Hello I'm from Canada','Hello I'm from America')=%%
```

Obviously this can be refined but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Hamish! That is what I thought, but wanted to see if there was some feature I wasn't aware of. Thanks!